# RT3090 slow and occacional disconnects

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, stretch

I have installed Linux-Mint 18 on a laptop with the RT3090 wireless card. Most older UBUNTU guide talk about installing an RT2860sta driver fixes the problem. I can't seem to find anything that will work with a modern distro. How can I get this working right?

My kern.log is full of these:

```
Aug 16 16:38:47 deadpool NetworkManager[812]: <error> [1471383527.5085] platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp2s0/mtu' to '1500': (22) Inva$
Aug 16 16:41:29 deadpool NetworkManager[812]: <error> [1471383689.2975] platform-linux: sysctl: failed to set '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp2s0/mtu' to '1500': (22) Inva$
Aug 16 16:42:40 deadpool kernel: [12683.456190] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:41 deadpool kernel: [12683.920294] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:41 deadpool kernel: [12684.388202] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:41 deadpool kernel: [12684.840302] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:42 deadpool kernel: [12685.296138] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:42 deadpool kernel: [12685.760195] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:43 deadpool kernel: [12686.224302] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:43 deadpool kernel: [12686.688299] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:44 deadpool kernel: [12687.152298] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Aug 16 16:42:44 deadpool kernel: [12687.620302] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

lspci shows:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

My problem is identical to this one. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749179

Comment: This answer is almost impossible to answer without additional information. What do the kernel logs say? What does syslog say? Which version of Mint are you running and which kernel version does your system have? Have you installed any additional drivers? What have you done to get it working? Are there any specific circumstances when the device disconnects?

Comment: In my opinion in these cases, unless your bios is locked to your wifi card (aka white list), your best bet is to simply order a modern card. $10 to $30. Dramatic improvement. I didn't check compatibility for your laptop ( it does have great built in linux support), but this is an example http://m.ebay.com/itm/190897053836?_mwBanner=1

Comment: OK I added more info. Check it out.